# How do I lock the Y but not the X in a kv screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to build a screen with 6 labels at the top, 6 inputs below the top labels, and then an infinite amount of labels generated below the inputs.
The columns + rows of the labels/inputs should align with each other.

When resizing the window, the X of each should change, but the Y should stay the same (making blank room for additional labels at the bottom). To make it more clear I imitated the situation in Excel:

[Window before resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNWNP.png) // [Window after resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhhej.png)

I tried the Grid Layout (where the X and Y always resize with the window -> doesn't work for my idea) and the Float Layout (where positioning everything (especially the generated labels) can't possibly be the best solution.

I am **not** looking for the logic behind generating the Labels below. Just the layout in .kv.

**UPDATE:**

After experimenting with @MisterNox 's code, I implemented it into my test project. When I click the "+" Button to add lines, I run into the problem that the two top rows are being pushed further up making the first row unreadable.

My code looks as follows and should be reproducable:

test_main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, TransitionBase, ShaderTransition, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.animation import Animation
import time
import csv


Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1024')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '768')

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(width=self.on_window_width)

    def on_window_width(self, instance, value):
        self.ids.stock_list_layout.width = value
        for obj in self.ids.my_window.children:
            if isinstance(obj, Label):
                obj.width = value/6

    def do_something(self):
        print("HEL")
        self.ids.my_window.add_widget(Label(text="TEST", size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width/6, 35)))
        self.ids.my_window.add_widget(Label(text="TEST", size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width / 6, 35)))
        self.ids.my_window.add_widget(Label(text="TEST", size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width / 6, 35)))
        self.ids.my_window.add_widget(Label(text="TEST", size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width / 6, 35)))
        self.ids.my_window.add_widget(Label(text="TEST", size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width / 6, 35)))
        self.ids.my_window.add_widget(Label(text="TEST", size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width / 6, 35)))

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv



kv = Builder.load_file("testing.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

testing.kv:

```
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
WindowManager:
    MyWindow:

<MyWindow>:
    GridLayout:
        id: my_window
        cols:6
        size_hint_y: None
        size_hint_x: None
        pos_hint:{"left":1,"top":1}
        width: Window.width

        Label:
            text:"LABEL"
            height: 35
            #size_hint:(0.16666,None)
        Label:
            height: 35
            #size_hint:(0.16666,None)
            text:"LABEL"
        Label:
            height: 35
            #size_hint:(0.16666,None)
            text:"LABEL"
        Label:
            height: 35
            #size_hint:(0.16666,None)
            text:"LABEL"
        Label:
            text:"LABEL"
            height: 35
            #size_hint:(0.16666,None)
        Label:
            text:"LABEL"
            height: 35
            #size_hint:(0.16666,None)

        TextInput:
            height: 35
            size_hint:(1,None)
        TextInput:
            height: 35
            size_hint:(1,None)
        TextInput:
            height: 35
            size_hint:(1,None)
        TextInput:
            height: 35
            size_hint:(1,None)
        Button:
            text:"+"
            on_release:
                root.do_something()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to give you a short example with a Gridlayout. **To adjust the width of your labels when the width of the screen is changing you could use a bind method on the Window.width.** You could still write your code in kv and just add the bind method in your app's build method of course, this is just an example.

Everytime the width of the window changes it will call the callback method which adjusts your label width according to the overall width. Then you could set a height for the labels. As this is static now and you did not set a height bind it will stay the same even if it goes out of the window viewport.

Here is a short code snippets only with some dummy labels to show you the procedure:

**Example:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = 600, 400

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.columns = GridLayout(cols=5, size_hint_x=None, width=Window.width)
        for lbl in range(0,80):
            self.columns.add_widget(Label(text="Dummy", size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width/5, 50)))
        Window.bind(width=self.on_window_width)

        return self.columns

    def on_window_width(self, instance, value):
        self.columns.width = value
        for obj in self.columns.children:
            if isinstance(obj, Label):
                obj.width = value/5


MyApp().run()
```

**[UPDATE]**

As you asked for kv integration, here is basically the same example from above, just with some kv integration. Basically you can integrate the labels/textinputs into the kv string, but I just wanted to add a lot of dummy labels so I kept this action in my python code.

The difference is that I assigned an id to the Gridlayout to access it easily with `self.ids.id_name` within my python code.

**bind explanation**

Regarding the bind method, this is a method which listens to changes of the assigned attribute and in case of a change it fires the callback method.

Lets take my example `Window.bind(width=self.on_window_width)`: The object who calls the method is the one with the attribute you want to look for. In our case we want to look for changes in the window width. Thats why Window is our acting object. Within the bracket you are going to name the attribute first and then the callback method which should be fired when changes occur.

A callback method takes three attributes, self (the object the method belongs to), the instance (in our case it is Window) and the changed value of the attribute we listened to in our bind method. Then you can do what ever you want with this value. We adjust the width of our labels to let them spread along with the window. Hopefully I explained it good enough.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

Window.size = 600, 400

kv = """
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

<MyScreen>:
    name: 'first'
    GridLayout:
        id: columns
        cols: 5
        size_hint_x: None
        width: Window.width

"""

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        for lbl in range(0,80):
            self.ids.columns.add_widget(Label(text="Dummy", size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width/5, 50)))
        Window.bind(width=self.on_window_width)

    def on_window_width(self, instance, value):
        self.ids.columns.width = value
        for obj in self.ids.columns.children:
            if isinstance(obj, Label):
                obj.width = value/5


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)

        WMan = ScreenManager()
        myscreen = MyScreen()

        WMan.add_widget(myscreen)

        return WMan


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I tried in my kv: `GridLayout: width: root.on_window_width` (the method is inside the screens class). This does not seem to work as on_window_width does not return the width. Also, I don't really understand the `Window.bind...` step in your example, can you please elaborate? -> excuse my confusion, I am new to this :)

Comment: I added an example which uses some kv integration and I tried to explain the bind method in a proper way. Hopefully it helps you.

Comment: Great example! I experimented with your code a bit and managed to build it into my project. Now I encounter the problem that, after adding 1 (or more) rows via the "+" button, the first to rows merge into each other. I will provide the example code for this in my main post.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it is because you have to adjust the height of your layout when you add a new line of labels. Write a method in your MyWindow class like `def adjust_height(self, widget): widget.height = widget.height + 35`. The 35 is because your new added line has a height of 35. Then add this `self.adjust_height(self.ids.my_window)` to your do_something method. One more thing, you should check your code as it throws tons of error messages when you change the window size.